# nginx proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For with allow/deny something wrong

Tags: nginx, x-forwarded-for

Nginx's conf:

```
location / {
    deny 192.168.1.1;
    allow 127.0.0.1/24;
    deny all;
    default_type application/json;
}
```

If I request the http://192.168.1.101:8000 with no header ,nginx return 403.

If I request the http://192.168.1.101:8000 with set `header[" X-Forwarded-For "] = 127.0.0.1` ,nginx return 200.

So how can I denied the illegal IP's request ？

Comment: You're only allowing connections over localhost. Any external request will be denied

Comment: Yes, it's my want to.

Comment: Are you using the X-Forwarded-For header in your backend apps? If not, you can override it with an empty string in this location

Comment: I want to know how can I denied the fake requests?